# Schema lost with ApacheBahir Stuctured Streaming connector on ApacheSpark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mqtt, watson-iot, apache-bahir

I'm trying to hook-up an ApacheSpark Structured Stream to a MQTT topic (IBM Watson IoT Platform on IBM Bluemix in this case).

I'm creating the structured stream as follows:

```
val df = spark.readStream 
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .option("username","a-vy0z2s-q6s8r693hv")
    .option("password","B+UX(aWuFPvX")
    .option("clientId","a:vy0z2s:a-vy0z2s-zfzzckrnqf")
    .option("topic", "iot-2/type/WashingMachine/id/Washer02/evt/voltage/fmt/json")
    .load("tcp://vy0z2s.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883")
```

So far so good, in REPL I get back this df object as follows:

> df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, timestamp:
>   timestamp]

I've learned from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018183/schema-issue-with-apachebahir-stuctured-streaming-connector-on-apachespark-strea) that I have to change the client ID every time I connect. So this is solved, but if I start to read from the stream using this line:

> val query = df.writeStream.   outputMode("append").
>   format("console").start()

Then the resulting schema looks like this:

> df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, timestamp: timestamp]

And the data as follows:

[image]

This means my JSON stream is converted into a stream of string object containing the JSON representation.

Is this a limitation of ApacheBahir?

Also providing a schema doesn't help since the following code resembles into the same result:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(
    StructField("count",LongType,true)::
    StructField("flowrate",LongType,true)::
    StructField("fluidlevel",StringType,true)::
    StructField("frequency",LongType,true)::
    StructField("hardness",LongType,true)::
    StructField("speed",LongType,true)::
    StructField("temperature",LongType,true)::
    StructField("ts",LongType,true)::
    StructField("voltage",LongType,true)::
Nil)

:paste
val df = spark.readStream
    .schema(schema)
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .option("username","a-vy0z2s-q6s8r693hv")
    .option("password","B+UX(a8GFPvX")
    .option("clientId","a:vy0z2s:a-vy0z2s-zfzzckrnqf4")
.option("topic", "iot-2/type/WashingMachine/id/Washer02/evt/voltage/fmt/json")
    .load("tcp://vy0z2s.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:1883")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many `DataSources`, including, [but not limited to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41378447/6910411) [`MQTTStreamSource`](https://github.com/apache/bahir/blob/master/sql-streaming-mqtt/src/main/scala/org/apache/bahir/sql/streaming/mqtt/MQTTStreamSource.scala#L75), have fixed schema, which consist of a message and a timestamp. Schema is not lost, is simply not parsed and it is an expected behavior.

If schema is fixed and known up front you should be able to use `from_json` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json

df.withColumn("value", from_json($"value", schema))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the parsing (as I've not four the "from_json" method anymore) I've used

> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.json_tuple

and the following code, it works as well:

> df.withColumn("value",json_tuple($"value","myColumnName"))